# Horizontally Align Fixed DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #rectangle {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id='rectangle' style='background-color:red;'></div>
            <div id='rectangle' style='background-color:green;'></div>
            <div  id='rectangle' style='background-color:black;'></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is the example code. I want all three boxes to appear side by side, using css. Any way of doing that? I want to use position:fixed, because I want them to appear on the bottom-right corner of the page without disturbing the rest of the page. These boxes will be chat boxes to tell you the truth.

Comment: You have invalid markup **Id attributes should be unique in a HTML page** use classes instead

Comment: And you say you use `position:fixed` but you are not using that. Give them 3 different id's and three different styles.

Answer (score 4):

I created this jsbin for you: http://jsbin.com/ikulem/13/edit
note that you have to use class instead of id for the rectangles since you are having more than one element

The CSS:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.rectangle {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px
}
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:red;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:green;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:black;'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should include the relevant code of your solution in your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.rectangles {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;

}
.rectangle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='rectangles'>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:red;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:green;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:black;'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

NB. Don't use IDs if you're using it multiple times on a page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty fix
Here is the body

```
<body>
  <div class='rectangle' id="red"></div>
  <div class='rectangle' id="green"></div>
  <div class='rectangle' id="black"></div>
</body>
```

here is the css

```
#wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}

.red{
    background:red;
}

.green{
    background: green;
}
.black{
    background:black;
}
```

relevant jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tlwr/xLTJE/1/

Comment: @toby.. Looks like I edited your post by mistake.. Sorry abt that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I used a Javascript function to do it for me.. thanks anyways.

```
    function restructureChatBoxes() {
        align=0;
        $(".shout_box").each(function(index) {
            console.log ( index );
            if (align == 0) {
                $(this).css('right', '0px');
            } else {
                width = (align)*(240+2);
                $(this).css('right', width+'px');
            }
            align++;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use javascript when you could use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #shape{
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
   }
   .rectangle{
     float: left;
     width: 150px;
     height: 200px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="shape">
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:red;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:green;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:black;'></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works exactly how you want it. Checkout a live version [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tsHoa)!

I would also recommend moving the CSS to a separate file, as well as omitting the inline CSS for the background colours and putting these within the CSS file as well. This would make the code cleaner. For example:

The CSS:

```
.red{background-color:red}
.green{background-color:green}
.black{background-color:black}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="shape">
  <div class='red rectangle'></div>
  <div class='green rectangle'></div>
  <div class='black rectangle'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use the same id three times.

You could use

```
<div id='rectangle-01' style='background-color:red;'></div>
<div id='rectangle-02' style='background-color:green;'></div>
<div id='rectangle-03' style='background-color:black;'></div>
```

instead.

The css you should use if you adapt the ids:

```
#rectangle-01 {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}

#rectangle-02 {
    position:fixed;
    right:150px;
    bottom:0;
    width: 150px;  //so the divs don't overlap
    height: 200px;
}

#rectangle-03 {
    position:fixed;
    right:300px;
    bottom:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Of course, the whole thing would be better with classes.
You could make a div with position:fixed and right: 0 + bottom: 0 and then place the chatboxes inside it:

```
<div id='chatboxes'>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:red;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:green;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='background-color:black;'></div>
</div>
```

The css for this would be:

```
#chatboxes {
    positon:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

#chatboxes .rectangle{
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
```